# Set CSS class for a View programmatically in a hook

Tags: views, 8, hooks

I want to set an extra class for the first page of a paged View.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function my_module_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() === 'my_view' && $view->current_display === 'page_1') {
    // Somehow set/override the css class here.
  }
}
```

How can I change the CSS class set in the advanced settings of the View?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
$view->display_handler->setOption('css_class', 'your_class');
```

Good luck!

Comment: `setOption` is the correct method. Thanks! Are the options documented anywhere?

Comment: Yes, good catch. You need to look at `DisplayPluginBase::defaultableSections()` for a list of the options.

Answer (score 2):

It works in drupal 9

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view().
 */
function MODULE_NAME_views_pre_view($view, $display_id, $args) {
  if ($view->id() == 'YOUR_VIEW_ID' && $display_id == 'YOUR_DISPLAY_NAME') {
    $view->display_handler->setOption('css_class', 'CLASS-NAME');
  }
}
```